# How to design Zener diode for a kickback voltage protection of motor?

Tags: power, diodes, motor, zener, kickback

- Vcc: 34 VDC
- Motor load current: 5 A

How to design motor kickback voltage protection of Zener diode?

[image]

Comment: I removed all the minus ('-') signs from your post as I didn't think they were intentional. If Vcc = 34 V where did you get the 150 V specification from? What are you trying to protect?

Comment: ok i am designing a Zener diode for a positive and negative kickback voltage of motor how to calculate ZENER power dissipation....

Comment: Now you've changed the requirements. Your question doesn't mention reversal (which is where your positive and negative comes from?). You calculate Zener power dissipation the same way as anything else: *P = VI* but this is changing with respect to time. Add a schematic of your circuit showing what you want to protect (you didn't answer that information request) and where you intend to insert your Zener diode.

Comment: OK, schematic added. For future questions please crop the image. 60% of it is white space.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fijSUa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two options.*

The diodes sketched in your diagram will work. Figure 1a shows them drawn a little more clearly. Whichever way the motor is running the current will be diverted to the power supply - if it can take it.

Figure 1b uses two Zener diodes back-to-back to allow for forward and reverse. The Zener voltage needs to be > V2. The peak power in the diodes will be \$ P = V_{ZD}I_{MOTOR} \$. The peak current will be \$ I_{MOTOR} \$.

I don't think you will find a 5 A Zener diode too easily. If your 5 A number is the running current you will have much higher current during a motor stall. Your protection circuit needs to survive this too.

Comment: Ok I am taking as a reference for this diode 1N5368B Vzd is 47V and my motor peak current is 8A so P=47*8=376W is it correct but how to assume....

Comment: Check the \$ I_R \$ of that diode in the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ie/datasheet/2/308/1N5333B_D-1801430.pdf). It's only 2.7 A.

Comment: So What are the parameters to consider to calculate the power dissipation of my schematic Zener diode.....

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a zener diode, a standard general purpose diode is good enough.

A flyback diode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) that short the back EMF (voltage) that can harm your driver electronic circuit.

Comment: You're probably right but the Zener will quench the current more quickly than a diode and bring the motor to a stop in a shorter time. It may be important in some applications but probably not in this one.

Comment: Well, there are several design suggestions in the wikipedia page, even schotty diodes is suggested.

Comment: Sure, a schottky diode can be used, but it would also make the motor run even longer than a standard diode. Depends on application if that is a good thing, bad thing, or irrelevant thing.

Comment: @Transistor Quenching the current and stopping the motor are two different things: the motor may keep rotating even when the current though it drops to zero. As such, the quickest way to bring the motor to a stop is shorting it.

Comment: @Dmitry, I think you're right. In my comment I'm only treating it as an inductor. I didn't consider inertia or external driving.